# Convert number to byte with N bits set

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I have a number in range 1-8.

I want to convert it to

```
0b00000001  // 1
0b00000011  // 2
0b00000111  // 3
0b00001111  // 4
0b00011111  // 5
0b00111111  // 6
0b01111111  // 7
0b11111111  // 8
```

Can it be done without a switch or a for loop?
Ideally with a simple formula.

Comment: Downvotes are usually because of short question, missing research trace or limited problem explanation. Here, your question was shorter than most people are expecting.

Comment: Well, short, but what should I add? Pasting my failed for loop approach wouldn't add anything to the question.

Comment: ^ It would show that you did some work and tried something, that you don't just ask for code (If you show your effort and an attempt you will get an upV from me :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you are looking for is

```
(1 << v) - 1
```